# Rotas com parâmetros dando indefinido

Tags: react, react-native, react-navigation

Tenho um FlatList onde cada card me direciona para uma nova tela:

```
render() {
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={
          () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Post', { 
              "title": this.props.item.title, 
              "image": this.props.item.image, 
              "description": this.state.description})
         }>
```

Na minha tela de Post eu chamo meu parâmetro:

```
{this.props.navigation.state.params.title}
```

Que me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: 
  undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.state.params.title')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você consegue ser redirecionado e estes parâmetros que você enviou para a rota POST (que você carrega com this.props.item) não estão vazios.

Se isto estiver certo, o problema é que a sua tela "Post" não está recebendo o navigation. Quando você cria as rotas de sua aplicação, o navigation é enviado como props para as telas que você informou. Se por exemplo uma destas telas tiver um componente dentro, este componente filho não herda o navigation.

Uma forma de contornar isso seria utilizar o "withNavigation" na hora de exportar a sua tela.  Aqui tem um exemplo disso.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class Post extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title="Back"
        onPress={() => {
          this.props.navigation.goBack();
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default withNavigation(Post);
```

Aqui tem mais informações:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html

Comment: Ele já estava exportado usando o withNavigator, porém nas minhas rotas, no stacknavigator, a tela post estava fora, se é que me entende, mas deu crt.